# Internal frame changes does not compile

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I'm making a small application. I have a `JFrame` and there is a desktop pane in it.
I want to load a `JInternalFrame` to it.

My code is as below.

```
void dpload(){
        Patients patient = new Patients();
        dp_patient.add(patient);
        patient.setVisible(true);
  }
```

*Patients = JInternalFrame* 
*patient = created object* 
*dp_patient =  desktopPane*

When I test it for the first time, it compiles fine.  But if I do any modification for the `JInternalFrame` and run, it does not change its modifications.

But when I change the object name (patient) and run again, changes happens.

for an example;

i changed the size of a button in JInternalFrame.
When i run the project, size has not changed.
 If i change the object name (patient>>> patients) size change is taken place.

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) *"How can I fix this?"*  I still don't understand the question.  If this is a compilation error, copy/paste the error.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: hi Please specify what is your JFrame and JInternalFrame object name. What is your dp_patient and patient.

Comment: There is no error. All working fine. Im using netbeans 6.0.1. when i clean the project and run again, the problem wont arise for the first time.

Comment: *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*